# A logo on top of a colored titlepage?

Tags: titles

i want to place a logo on a colored titlepage, but google search and manual reading did not helped me out. May some of the experts help me out?

Here is my coding-sample, inspired by the "Heidelberg" theme:

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}            
\usepackage{lmodern}               
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.10,0,0}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
\definecolor{white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
    \newgeometry{left=5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} 
    \noindent
    \color{white}
    {\LARGE \textsf{Subject} } 
    \par
    \noindent
    \color{white}
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent \huge\textbf{\textsf{Title}}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent\huge\textbf{\textsf{Subtitle} }}
    \par

\vfill

\begin{flushright}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{logo.jpg}
\end{flushright}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry 

\nopagecolor lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where do you want to place the logo? On top of the page or somewhere on top of the colour layer?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this ? (Well, maybe not quite…)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.10,0,0}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10}
\definecolor{white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
    \newgeometry{left=5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}
    \noindent
\begin{flushright}
\vspace*{-3cm}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pepe-le-pew1}
 \vspace{2cm}
\end{flushright}
    \color{white}
    {\LARGE \textsf{Subject} }
    \par
    \noindent
    \color{white}
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent \huge\textbf{\textsf{Title}}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent\huge\textbf{\textsf{Subtitle} }}
    \par

\vfill%

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\nopagecolor lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using Bernard's (+1) subject and title as a start but using a different methodology and fewer packages,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
\fill[orange] (0,0)--(\paperwidth,0)--(\paperwidth,\paperheight)--(0,\paperheight)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[anchor=north east] (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2in]{pig}};
\end{tikzpicture}

    \noindent
    \color{white}
    {\LARGE \textsf{Piglets} } 
    \par
    \noindent
    \color{white}
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent \huge\textbf{\textsf{Cute pigs}}}
    \par\medskip
    {\noindent\huge\textbf{\textsf{Out and about} }}
    \par




\end{titlepage}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion using package `scrlayer` and defining a new layer page style for the title page. This package is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. Note that `scrlayer-scrpage`, the KOMA package for headers and footers, bases on `scrlayer`. So if you use `scrlayer-scrpage` in your document there is no additional package needed. The layers are already in the first run on the disered place.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagebackground}{cmyk}{1,.10,0,0}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
\definecolor{titlepagetext}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0} 

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{%
  titlepage.bg,%
  titlepage.logo%
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  contents=\textcolor{titlepagebackground}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}
]{titlepage.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLR{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}}}
]{titlepage.logo}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \newgeometry{left=5cm,right=1cm}
  \color{titlepagetext}\sffamily
  \begin{flushleft}
    {%
      \LARGE 
      Subject
      \par
    }
    \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}}
    \par
    {%
      \huge\bfseries
      Title\par
      Subtitle\par
    }
  \end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry 
lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It would also be possible to use an additional layer for the title page text. Then you do not have to change the page geometry for the title page and package `geometry` can be removed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagebackground}{cmyk}{1,.10,0,0}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
\definecolor{titlepagetext}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0} 

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{%
  titlepage.bg,%
  titlepage.logo,%
  titlepage.text%
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  contents=\textcolor{titlepagebackground}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}
]{titlepage.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLR{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}}}
]{titlepage.logo}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  hoffset=5cm,
  width=\paperwidth-6cm,
  contents={%
    \color{titlepagetext}\sffamily
    \begin{flushleft}
      {%
        \LARGE 
        Subject
        \par
      }
      \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}}
      \par
      {%
        \huge\bfseries
        Title\par
        Subtitle\par
      }
    \end{flushleft}
  }
]{titlepage.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \null
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is using a layer here better? Can you add an explanation?