# Image at the top of the page + margins

Tags: graphics, margins, texmaker, headline

I am trying to do my company paper. After few tries I finally put my image at the top of the page. But after that when I am using `\usepackage{scrextend}` and trying to change margins, the text is above my picture. Can anyone help me?

And one more question: can I put some text ON the image? For example 3 lines, white font on the left side?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=0.01cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.01cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle {empty}
\usepackage{scrextend} 

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.1\textwidth} 

\vspace{-18pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{PAPIERfirmowygora.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{2cm}
Some text.
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

The link to the image: [image: PAPIERfirmowygora]

Comment: Do any of the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320123/a-logo-on-top-of-a-colored-titlepage/320148#320148 help?

Answer (score 1):

To get the image at the top of your pager you should get rid of your used environment `wrapfigure`. Use instead only `\includegraphics` like this:

```
\vspace{-18pt}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{PAPIERfirmowygora.jpg} % <============
```

The `\vspace` is used to move the image at the top of the page and `\noindent` is needed to get no white space at the beginning of the image.

To get white text on the left of the image you can use package `textpos`:

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
```

Then you can use the following code to add the white text (remember to call package `xcolor` to get color `white` be defined):

```
\begin{textblock*}{12cm}(5mm,5mm) % <===================================
  \color{white}\noindent
  Text in first line \\
  Text in second line \\
  Text in third line
\end{textblock*} % <====================================================
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} % <=================================================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=0.01cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.01cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle {empty}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % <==============================
\usepackage{blindtext} % <==============================================


\begin{document}

\vspace{-18pt}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{PAPIERfirmowygora.jpg} % <============

\begin{textblock*}{12cm}(5mm,5mm) % <===================================
  \color{white}\noindent
  Text in first line \\
  Text in second line \\
  Text in third line
\end{textblock*} % <====================================================

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{2cm}
Some text.
\blindtext
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you so much. Didnt know about those packages, searched a lot of forums etc.